# How to add SharePoint links in Folder(s) or Header?

Tags: sharepoint-online, 2016, content-and-structure

Actually my `SharePoint page content` looks like below image

[image]

- `SPSights` is SharePoint logo
- `My Team`, `Resources` and `CX HUB` is the Headers.

Each of the Header consists of different site pages.

Now, I need to hide that `default site page` and `add my custom link` to be shown under `resources Header`.

I thought this header is a ribbon. So, I tried to create a `custom action` using `SharePoint Designer` but that created button has displayed in the ribbon.

And when I click that header it should to re-direct to custom link not to the default link. How and Where to `Add Links` to that header?

Comment: Use Navigation settings, under site settings=> look and feel

Comment: Please provide me full procedure of adding. @PraveenPudi

Comment: In navigation setting, how to add links to that header?

Comment: is it Team Site or Publishing Site

Comment: Publishing site

Comment: Is that header made in the Top Link Bar (of SP master page) or is it a custom menu created on a page? In the first case, go to Site Settings and next to Top Link Bar under Look and Feel. In the last case, you would need to edit the page and format the text. I would suggest using the Edit Source button but you would need a little HTML knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to Site Settings >> Navigation Under Look and Feel
   [image]
2. On Navigation page, you will find Links like My Team , resources etc , Click on it and hide.
   [image]
3. You can add new headings or links if required.
4. Click Ok.

Comment: Yeah @saira. Actually i tried this but its look like this /sharepointSiteName/SiteOne/SiteTwo... When i click SiteOne it goes to the subsite....

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have `SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure`feature enabled in site collections features, Go to `site settings page-->Navigation>`Scroll to the bottom of the page and you will find the `Global Navigation` option. You should find all the above links in that section. Just edit and modify the links as per your need!